# Scala: Why do I get a type mismatch error when I use "Option"?

Tags: scala, types

I'm new to Scala. I have a Scala function, and one of its arguments uses "Option":

```
def generateTimeSnippet(startOfSentence: Double, endOfSentence: Option[Double]): (Double, Option[Double]) = {
   ...
}
```

When I call this function, I give literal values to the arguments:

```
val snippets = generateTimeSnippet(startOfSentence = 10d, endOfSentence = 20.5)
```

But this results in a type mismatch error:
"type mismatch;  found   : Double(10.0) required: Option[Double]"

I find this very odd. Why is this happening? Am I not supposed to be allowed to use Doubles for an argument that is defined as Option[Double]?

Comment: It may be useful to explicitly point out here that `Option` is not a special language feature. It is an ordinary type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of course, for an argument of the type `Option[Double]`, you can not send in the type `Double`. They are different types.

You can send in `Some(20.5)` which is of the type `Option[Double]`